# Can't stop a timer created within a function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, timer

I'm working on a project and in the project there is a function that creates a timer the creates another timer.

This function creates and starts the timers:

```
function dfcty_txt_fade(){
    var dfcty_alpha_timer:Timer = new Timer(500,1);
    dfcty_alpha_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,dfcty_alpha_wait);
    function dfcty_alpha_wait(event:TimerEvent){
        var dfcty_alpha_timer_alt:Timer = new Timer(50,10);
        dfcty_alpha_timer_alt.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,dfcty_alpha_wait_alt);
        function dfcty_alpha_wait_alt(event:TimerEvent){
            dfcty_txt.alpha -= .1;
        }
        dfcty_alpha_timer_alt.start();
    }
    dfcty_alpha_timer.start();
}
```

This code calls on that function:

```
function swag_listener(){
    this[difficulty_str].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,dfcty_fade);
    function dfcty_fade(event:MouseEvent){
        dfcty_txt_fade();
    }
}
```

The problem is, sometimes I want to stop and reset the timers using a different function, but I can't. I get an 1120 error saying Access of undefined property. I think that I can't stop/reset the timers because they've been created in that function. I suck at AS3. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 function dfcty_txt_fade(){
     var dfcty_alpha_timer:Timer = new Timer(500,1); 
     ...
```

try

```
 var dfcty_alpha_timer:Timer
 function dfcty_txt_fade(){
     dfcty_alpha_timer = new Timer(500,1);
     ...
```

This declares your timer instance *outside* the scope of the function which was hiding it from other functions.